# Python TCP server sending data without promt

Tags: python, tcp, server, client, communication

I have problem developing app in python.

I need to send data from server to client without prompt, but all examples I've found on internet are echo servers.

Server should have has static IP (127.0.0.1) and save clients IP on first connection. I need to send data from server to client for example every 5 seconds (until timeout) without server waiting to be asked for that data. Of course client sends another data in its own routine.

Server script:

```py
import socket

TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
TCP_PORT = 5010
BUFFER_SIZE = 512
MESSAGE = 'Hi'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
while(1):
    s.listen()

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Connection address:', addr)
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: 
            break
        print ("received data: ", data.decode())
        print ("address: ", addr[0])
        conn.send(MESSAGE.encode())  # echo
    print("Closing connection")
    conn.close()
```

and Client script:

```py
import socket
import sys
import logging
import time

HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 5010
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

for x in range(100):
    # Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        # Connect to server and send data
        sock.connect_ex((HOST, PORT))
        sock.sendall(bytes(data + "\n", "utf-8"))

        # Receive data from the server and shut down
        received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")
sock.close()
logging.info("Socket closed")

print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
print("Received: {}".format(received))
print("Size: ", sys.getsizeof(received), "bytes")

time.sleep(5)
```

I would really appreciate every help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please familiarise yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should at least add what you have tried (the code) and what part of the core acts faulty.

Comment: just added one of codes I've tried, thanks

Comment: `Server-Client` technology means that `server` sends response only when `client` sends request. In your situation server should work as client, and client should work as server. So after connection `server` has to loop and `send()` data and client has to loop all time and `recv()` data. (it may have to run it in separated thread)

Comment: So you proposing that every client and also main server should have server and client capabilities?
How would this be handled if only main server has static IP?
Is there some other protocol that would work in this example?

Comment: in old method (used in web browser without websockets) client/browser send requests every 5 seconds and ask for new data - server doesn't try to keep connection and don't send data if client doesn't ask for it.

Comment: in new method (browser with websocket) client/browser connect to server and keep it connection and run loop to receive data - so it behaves like server. And server after connection start sending data periodically - so it behaves like client. So client has to connect to server which has static IP and keep this connection to receive data - it can't disconnect.

Comment: do you have any examples for new method?

Comment: I have example but without `threading` so it works only with one client and client can't do other things

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having or what help you need. What is preventing you from writing code that does what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example in which server keeps connection and sends data every 5 seconds. At the same time server keeps connection and receives data in loop. But it blocks server and client and loops should work in separated threads

server:

```
import socket
import time
import datetime


TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
TCP_PORT = 5010
BUFFER_SIZE = 512
MESSAGE = 'Hi'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.listen() # it can be before loop

while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Connection address:', addr)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: 
            break
        print ("received data: ", data.decode())
        print ("address: ", addr[0])
        conn.send(MESSAGE.encode())  # echo

        # send data every 5 seconds - it should run in separated thread   
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            conn.send(str(datetime.datetime.now()).encode())

    print("Closing connection")
    conn.close()
```

client

```
import socket
import sys
import logging
import time

HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 5010
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

for x in range(100):
    # Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        # Connect to server and send data
        sock.connect_ex((HOST, PORT))
        sock.sendall(bytes(data + "\n", "utf-8"))

        # Receive data from the server and shut down
        received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")

        print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
        print("Received: {}".format(received))
        print("Size: ", sys.getsizeof(received), "bytes")

        # receive data periodically - it should run in thread
        while True:
            received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")
            print("Received: {}".format(received))


sock.close()
logging.info("Socket closed")
```

---

**EDIT:** version with `threading`. And with `queue` to send message to thread and stop it

server - classic construction. It can work with many clients at the same time

```
import socket
import time
import datetime
import threading

# --- functions ---

def process_client(conn, addr):
    print('Connection address:', addr)

    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: 
        return

    print("received data: ", data.decode())
    print("address: ", addr[0])
    conn.send(MESSAGE.encode())

    # send data every 5 seconds
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        conn.send( str(datetime.datetime.now()).encode() )

    conn.close()

# --- main ---

TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
TCP_PORT = 5011
BUFFER_SIZE = 512
MESSAGE = 'Hi'

#all_threads = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.listen() # it can be before loop

while True:
    print('wait for next client')
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    t = threading.Thread(target=process_client, args=(conn, addr))
    t.start()
    #all_threads.append(t)

#for t in all_threads: t.join()    
print("Closing connection")
s.close()
```

client - socket in thread so program can do other things

```
import socket
import sys
import logging
import time
import threading
import datetime
import queue

# --- functions ---

def receive_data(q):

    # Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        # Connect to server and send data
        sock.connect_ex((HOST, PORT))
        sock.sendall(bytes(data + "\n", "utf-8"))

        # Receive data from the server and shut down
        received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")

        print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
        print("Received: {}".format(received))
        print("Size: ", sys.getsizeof(received), "bytes")

        # receive data periodically - it should run in thread
        while True:
            received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")
            print("Received: {}".format(received))

            if not q.empty() and q.get() == 'stop':
                break 

    # sock.close() # doesn't need if you use `with ... as sock`
    print("Socket closed")

# --- main ---

HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 5011
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

q = queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=receive_data, args=(q,))
t.start()

# other code

#while True:
for x in range(10):
    print('    Local time:', datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(1)

q.put("stop") # message to thread to stop it

#t.join()
```

It would need some `try/except` (ie. to catch Cltr+C and stop threads) and code which stop threads.

---

BTW: some examples from other my answers [furas/python-examples/socket](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/socket) (on GitHub)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check that

Comment: I'm working on version with threading (PL: pracuje nad wersją z użyciem wątków)

Comment: Dziękuje bardzo za pomoc